# Unable to change node-webkit app icon in dock bar in MAC OSX

Tags: macos, node-webkit

I have changed nw.icns in /nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/ directory with new nw.icns file. My app.nw is located inside /nwjs.app/Contents/Resources/ directory. 
I used following command in terminal to run app

> open -n -a nwjs --args "path_to_nw directory"

But the app icon in dock bar of MAC doesn't changes it takes old NWJS default icon.[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.